# get the key while using firebase on ionic3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using firebase on my ionic project. You can see my dataset on firebase with the following image.

I want to get the $key to update the specific data. How can i get it?

You can check my code how to get datas from firebase.

```
getPaymentsFromArchive() {
    const userid = this.authData.showUser().uid;
    let profileData: any[] = [];

this.angularFireDatabase.list(`/users/${userid}/userPayments/${this.selectedYears}/${this.selectedMonths}/userSubscriptions`).subscribe(data => {
        profileData = data;
      });
}
```

[image]

I want to get $key: `"-L-hLB5VKoYRxKEvlNYj"`

[image]

Comment: What the version of AngularFire2 you are using? 
if you use 4 or 5 you can see this link https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#moving-away-from-key-and-value

Comment: importing that class while i using.  `import {AngularFireDatabase} from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
`  @Al-Mothafar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the keys in `userSubscriptions` this should work.

```
this.angularFireDatabase.list('/users/${userid}/userPayments/${this.selectedYears}/${this.selectedMonths}/userSubscriptions').subscribe(data => {
    profileData = data;    
    profileData.map(item => {
       console.log(item.$key);
    })
});
```

Comment: Just need to get key of specific 1 field.

Comment: you want 1 specific key...what is attached to it? how are you going to identify it?

Comment: Hi, http://prntscr.com/hl0ybb i have a page like this. And i click the button sending data to details page. You can check the data with the following image. http://prntscr.com/hl0yhw i tried to do something like that: `data.map(item => {
      this.key = item.$key;
    });` but does not work and throw `data.map is not a function`

Comment: are you using angularfire2 4.0 or 5.0?

Comment: what about the `forEach` loop? `data.forEach(item => { console.log(item.$key)})`

Comment: property subscribe doesn't exist with AngularFireList... what should I do please?

Comment: @M.Mariscal try `this.angularFireDatabase.list('xxx').valueChanges().subscribe(...`